# Microsoft Excel- Sum IF

Tags: microsoft-excel

How can I sum totals in Excel if the identifying mark is an asterisk *.  In column D I have numerous accounts only identified with an asterisk * in column E I have totals.  I need to write a formula that will sum only the accounts labeled as an *.  Thanks

Comment: Can you give a short example screenshot of what your data looks like?

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the following formula into all the cells in a new column

```
=IF(D1="*", E1, 0)
```

Then sum that column at the end of it

Comment: After reading your answer, I realise mine doesn't even answer the question. Nice work.

Comment: @Susan No problem.  Don't forget to check the check mark by the answer to mark it as accepted so I get credit.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **SUMIF** function to achieve that in only one step.

> SUMIF(range, criteria, [sum_range])

Just use the following formula in a new cell:

**`=SUMIF(D1:D99,"=~*",E1:E99)`**

Comment: Is the "~" so that "*" gets treated as a literal rather than a wildcard?  If so, might that vary by locale setting (need "\" in some locales)?  I'm using LO Calc and don't have ready access to Excel to test it, but in Calc, a plain asterisk works.

Comment: @fixer1234 In Excel, 
    ~? finds only the ? character;
    ~* finds only the * character;
    ? finds all single characters;
    * finds all strings of characters. I don't think it varies by locale settings.

Comment: No problem with the "?" or "*".  I was referring to "~".  My understanding is that "\" is typically used to treat the next character as a literal, so I was wondering if that difference ("~" vs. "\"), is locale-based.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `COUNTIF` for this.

This will count all the  cells with `*` between `A1` and `A15`:

`=COUNTIF(A1:A15,"*")`